# mwl calendar mark hour in different color

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I use the mwl calendar and I will mark the hour from 12 - 13 in another color inday view.
Is there a simple possibility to do this?

[image: mwl calendar]

**[EDIT]**
Now I have tried this one

```
<style type="text/css">
    .cal-day-hour-part:nth-of-type(2n) {
        background-color: #f00 !important;
    }
  </style>
```

with this plunker example:

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/djQ5jaj6KgW3SAjObOqj?p=preview)

and this works fine, than I have tried it with **.cal-day-hour-part:nth-of-type(3n)** and this does not work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What have you tried? Consider putting together a jsfiddle or plunkr showing your code.

Comment: My problem is that the hours do not have unique classes or ids. Therefore  I can not set the background color of the div container from 12-13. Does anyone have any other idea how I can do this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM is structured like this:

```
<div class="cal-day-hour">
  <div class="cal-day-hour-part">
  <div class="cal-day-hour-part">
</div>
<div class="cal-day-hour">
  <div class="cal-day-hour-part">
  <div class="cal-day-hour-part">
</div>
...
```

The `:nth-of-type(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, **of its parent**. There are at most 2 `.cal-day-hour-part` children of `.cal-day-hour` in your DOM. That's why 2n works but 3n does not.

Regarding your original question (and thanks for the edits to clarify), you'll want to use `:nth-of-type(n)` on `.cal-day-hour` instead, and stop using the counter `n` as you don't need it.

```
.cal-day-hour:nth-of-type(7) {
    background-color: #f00 !important;
}
```

[Here's an updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WRpA7wUJ6i6Mxrxe2M2K)